# How to escape backslashes in a filtered properties files with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, escaping, backslash, maven-resources-plugin

My **pom.xml** file looks like this:

```
<testResource>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>env.properties</include>
    </includes>
</testResource>
```

My **env.properties** looks like this:

```
my.path=${project.build.directory}
```

When I build the project, the **env.properties** is generated like below:

```
my.path=C:\\path\\to\\directory
```

How can I get the result below instead?

```
my.path=C:\\\\path\\\\to\\\\directory
```

Comment: Why do you want this output? `C:\\\\path\\\\to\\\\directory` is an incorrect path inside the properties file.

Comment: @Tunaki Well I'm using a third party library that mess around with filenames like this `C:pathtodirectory`. My actual workaround is to escape manually the filenames (`filename.replace("\\", "/")`) before passing them to the library.  I was hoping to find a pure Maven solution.

Comment: @Tunaki You replied faster than I correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird thing to want to do, but you could use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:regex-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html) goal. This goal enables the creation of a Maven property which is the result of applying a regular expression to some value, possibly with a replacement.

In this case, the regular expression would replace all blackslashes, i.e. `\\` since they need to be escaped inside the regular expression, and the replacement would be the 4 backslashes. Note that the plugin automatically escapes the regular expression for Java, so you don't need to also Java-escape it.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>escape-baskslashes</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <value>${project.build.directory}</value>
        <regex>\\</regex>
        <replacement>\\\\\\\\</replacement>
        <name>escapedBuildDirectory</name>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will store the wanted path inside the `escapedBuildDirectory` property, that you can later use as a standard Maven property like `${escapedBuildDirectory}`, inside your resource file. The property is created in the `validate` phase, which is the first phase invoked by Maven during the build, so that it could also be used anywhere else, as a plugin parameter.